# How to update (draw) a widget and only this widget in GTK

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

When I have, for instance the following widget hierarchy:

- Window

  - Box

    - Drawing Area 1
    - Drawing Area 2

and I call queue_draw on Drawing Area 1 then also Drawing Area 2 is updated (draw). Is this behavior intended and can I prevent this and only update Drawing Area 1, because of performance reasons.

Edit: Added a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pgi
pgi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from pgi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf
import cairo

class DrawingArea(Gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()

        self.id = id
        self.vexpand = True
        self.hexpand = True

        self.connect("draw", self.on_draw)

    def on_draw(self, area, context):
        print ("on_draw ", self.id)
        context.set_source_rgb (1, 0, 0)
        context.rectangle (0,0,20,20)
        context.fill ()
        return False

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_title("Test Draw Radial Gradient")
        self.set_default_size(400, 200)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.drawingArea1 = DrawingArea (1)
        self.drawingArea2 = DrawingArea (2)

        box = Gtk.Box ()
        box .pack_start (self.drawingArea1, True, True, 0)
        box .pack_start (self.drawingArea2, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Me")
        box .pack_start (button, True, True, 0)
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click_me_clicked)

        self.add(box)

    def on_click_me_clicked(self, button):
        print ("Button clicked")
        self.drawingArea1.queue_draw()

window = Window()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal and reproducible example so we can test ourselves.

Comment: Added example @BobMorane.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand Gtk source, it's some kind of intended behaviour. `queue_draw` leads to invalidation of part of window and it recursively updates widgets. Most likely (it's just guesses!) it tells `box` to be redrawn and box redraws all of it's children.

Anyway, your widgets should be always ready to be redrawn. If user resizes window -- it's many redraws. If he minimizes and brings window back -- it's another redraw.

First of all, make sure your redraw is a real bottleneck. Second, I'd suggest implementing some kind of caching or proxy: a cairo surface of the same size as widget, when your data changes you draw it there and on redraw you just paint that surface on widget's surface. Another approach would be preparing drawables in another thread (which is questionable if you use python), but again: start with some measurements and find out if redraw is really slow.